# Can't compile since upgrading to swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift

Since upgrading to swift 1.2 I can't compile my code because if this error message:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

There is absolutely no more specific error messages in my files so it's almost impossible to find the problem.

I ran this to try to find the culprit file:

```
xcodebuild -project myApp -scheme myApp;
```

and it pointed to 4 files that may cause issue but without specifying why. Here is the content of on of these file, do you see a single reason why swift 1.2 can't compile this ?

```
import Foundation

struct UserScore {
    static var scoreValue: Int = 0
    var myLabel: UILabel
}

//Called in HandleVote
class CalculateScore  {
    func updateScore(scoreLabel: UILabel) {
        UserScore.scoreValue += 1
        scoreLabel.text = String(UserScore.scoreValue)
    }
}

class UpdateScoreInParse {
    func updateScore () {
        let user = PFUser.currentUser()
        var query = PFUser.query()
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(user.objectId) {
            (score: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            } else {
                score.incrementKey("score")
                score.saveInBackground()
            }
        }
    }
}

class UpdateScoreLocally {
    func updateScore(label: UILabel) {
        let user = PFUser.currentUser()
        user.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (user: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let parseScore = Int(user["score"] as! NSNumber)
                UserScore.scoreValue = parseScore
                label.text = String(parseScore)
            } else {
                NSLog("Error: ", error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to clean your Derived Data, clean your build and eventually restart your XCode.

Comment: Did you update your command line tools as well as Xcode?

Comment: Also, in XCode 6.3 release notes, it is said that "Convert to Latest Swift may generate build errors when run. These errors can be safely ignored and don’t affect the source changes that are produced. "

Comment: I did all these thanks but it did not helped, see answer below that i'm posting

Comment: @HoaParis : The errors are red flags that prevents me from building

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, which seems unrelated to these files.
The problem turned to be the import of a third party library, that would cause this error if it resided outside the project directory. It never caused problem with swift < 1.2.

When I moved the library IN the project folder, these files stopped triggering error. I really don't know why since those files didn't import and didn't used that library. Anyway, I was able to clear those errors, but I have a new one, which fortunately, I have more explicit error for.

So it seems the above code doesn't have any specific problem.